# Calculating earthquake amplitude between Richter scale (M) 7.0 and 7.9

Tags: functions, logarithms

First time posting here. I didn't manage to find previous posts about this but if you find one, please link it.

I've been stuck working on a math assignment about calculating the range of an earthquake's amplitude, when the magnitude is between 7.0 and 7.9.

The formula I've been given is $$M=\log( \frac{A_{max}}{A_{0}})$$

The original assignment is not in English so I'll do my best to translate it.

> An earthquake is classified as especially strong, if its magnitude on the Richter scale is between $7.0 \leq M \leq 7.9$ . What is the range of the amplitudes corresponding to these limits? Give your answer as a function of the attenuation factor A<sub>0</sub>.

Furthest I've gotten is something like $$A_{max}(A_{0})=10^{M}*A_{0}$$

Where M is either 7.0 or 7.9 and A<sub>0</sub> is an arbitrary number, but this certainly isn't right.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Furthest I've gotten is something like $$A_{max}(A_{0})=10^{M}*A_{0}$$
>
> Where M is either 7.0 or 7.9 and A<sub>0</sub> is an arbitrary number, but this certainly isn't right.

Well, it *is* right. The minimum value of $M$, and hence the minimum possible value of $A_{max}$, is $10^7 \cdot A_{0}$; the maximum possible value is is $10^{7.9} \cdot A_{0}$. You can plug in both these values in the first formula to check that they are correct; the logarithm is a monotonous increasing function so the values in between correspond to an especially strong earthquake too.

Comment: Okay. Perhaps I am misunderstanding but I don't understand how I would determine the value of $A_{0}$. I know that the correct answer is $$XA_{0} \leq A_{max} \leq YA_{0}$$ With X representing value of the amplitude at M = 7.0 and Y at M = 7.9, but I don't know the actual values. Sorry, should have included that in the original post.

Comment: That does not matter; you're asked to give it as a function of $A_0$; the actual value of $A_0$ does not matter.